# Google Run Managed - how keep a minimum number of instances and not have 0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

We have a set of services deployed on google run platform managed for a web application and whenever there is no traffic, it seems the services go to sleep and then it takes a long time to wake them up whenever new traffic comes in.
Is there a way to keep at least one instance of the services alive without having to fake traffic by regularly sending queries to those containers? The option is disabled in the UI and in the command line the only option available seems to be when running anthos cluster, not fully managed:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--min-instances

We are using the following command to deploy our services:

Answer (score 1):

If your question is related to Managing instance in the App Engine ,you can use the manual scaling option . Manual scaling specifies the number of instances that continuously run regardless of the load level. This allows tasks such as complex initializations and applications that rely on the state of the memory over time.Please see the [link-1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types) for the details.

If your question is related to How to set a minimum scale to 1 for k-native on GKE? please see the details on [link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573188/how-to-set-a-minimum-scale-to-1-for-k-native-on-gke)